# Multiple exceptions handling from mysqli in PHP 8

Tags: php, exception, mysqli

I'm transitioning to using exceptions in my projects since PHP 8 has that the default behavior. There's one piece of code that I can't figure out how to convert to exceptions since there are multiple queries and I need error handling on each of them. My old goes like this

```
$query1 = mysqli_query($connect, "MYSQL QUERY");
if($query1){
    $query2 = mysqli_query($connect, "ANOTHER QUERY");
    if($query2){
        // alright
    } else {
        // handle error on $query2
    }
} else {
    // handle error on $query1
}
```

My new code is something like this

```
try {
    mysqli_query($connect, "MYSQL QUERY");
    mysqli_query($connect, "ANOTHER QUERY");
    
} catch(Exception $e){
    // handle error from both?
}
```

It can handle error on both queries but I don't know which one was it that failed. How can I get that? Do I have to nest `try catch`, that feels like a hacky implementation.

Comment: I usually recommend running as little code as possible in a `try` block, that way the `catch` can be for a more specific failure. So for this, I’d use two `try` blocks.

Comment: Since second query depends on first, you recommend nesting try catch?

Comment: Why are you opposed to nesting them to begin with here? The if/else statements of the original code were nested already, did you lose sleep over that back then as well ...?

Comment: I don't know. Nested try catch "seems" ugly while nested if else doesn't. I guess I have my answer hehe

Comment: I don’t know your original code logic, beyond what you’ve posted, but I prefer a “return early” style when possible. With your `if` version, I would invert thing and do `if(!$query){/*die or return or similar*/}`. In my mind, these aren’t nested, one has a condition based on the other, however. But that might not be the case for you, so nesting is totally fine, too.

Comment: Wouldn't the exception tell you exactly which one failed? It contains the error message and the line number. If you have different error handling logic for each query then what's the point in wrapping them in a single try-catch? Each one will have a separate catch logic, right?

Comment: @Whip what kind of handling? The answer really depends on that. It could be nested, it could be parallel, it could be some custom logic, it could be no try catch at all. For example, if it should abort the execution then it one scenario. if it should keep to the next query it will be another.

Comment: You can see from my old code that if `query1` fails `query2` will not run so that is what I want going forward as well. @ChrisHaas I can't use return since this code is not in a function. For now, I've decided to nest `try catch`